# How to get data by filtering with two different dates in django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, django

This is my model;

```
class FundData(models.Model):
   fund = models.ForeignKey(Fund, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="data_of_fund", verbose_name="Fund")
   date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, editable=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Date")
   price = models.FloatField(max_length=15, blank=False, verbose_name="Fund Price")
```

This is my frontend where i want to choose dates;

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-end">
        <div>
            <label>Starting Date</label>
            <input id="startDatePicker" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="mx-2">
            <label>Ending Date</label>
            <input id="endDatePicker" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <a onclick="getFundReturnsByDate()" class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:void(0);"> Show<i
                class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

All i want is that user should choose 2 dates and bring the data of the selected dates in a table.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#range) filter.

```
FundData.objects.filter(date__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

Comment: How can i get the value of datepicker into start_date & end_date?

Comment: @turkaybeyazay, better you read Django document. please read forms related section.

Comment: i managed to get the value of datepicker but now i take an error named wrong format for date format, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
FundData.objects.filter(date__range=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"])
```

Or if you are just trying to filter month wise:

```
FundData.objects.filter(date__year='2011', 
                      date__month='01')
```